# Using Generic Type for same functionality

Tags: java, generics, java-8

I am having a scenario where two functions are identically similar but the Class object used in the two differ, similar like this,

```
public int function1(inputObject input){
    LeadMaster lead= input.getLeadMaster();
    PropertyUtils.setProperty(lead, input.getKey(), input.getValue());
    return 0;
}
```

And similarly other function like,

```
public int function2(inputObject input){
    DealMaster deal= input.getDealMaster();
    PropertyUtils.setProperty(deal, input.getKey(), input.getValue());
    return 0;
}
```

How can I use the generic class for the master object in above object? I haven't used generics yet.

Comment: You don't necessarily need generics here. Can't you define some base interface / class that defines some "generic" property? Worst case you could simply use Object here.

Comment: Thank you @GhostCat. Can you please show How do I define a generic property for above LeadMaster and DealMaster, an example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you wish your method to work with any property of the `inputObject` class, you can pass a functional interface that returns the required property of a given `inputObject` instance:

```
public <T> int function(inputObject input, Function<inputObject,T> func) {
    T obj = func.apply(input);
    PropertyUtils.setProperty(obj, input.getKey(), input.getValue());
    return 0;
}
```

Now you can call this method with

```
function(input,inputObject::getLeadMaster);
```

or

```
function(input,inputObject::getDealMaster);
```

Comment: oh damn - absolutely yes :)

Comment: Thank you @Eran. I Was looking for the same only.

Comment: What would be interesting to see would be how the `PropertyUtils.setProperty` method would work if `LeadMaster` and `DealMaster` don't share a common interface.

Comment: @CKing I have no idea what `PropertyUtils.setProperty` does. I made no assumptions about it (except of assuming that the OP's original two methods pass compilation).

Comment: @Eran I was wondering what would happen if they don't share a common interface and `setProperty` has an overloaded form for the two object types. But looks like the OP has accepted the answer so that is not the case :)

Comment: @CKing I didn't think about the possibility of `setProperty` being overloaded. Good point.

Answer (score 0):

You could re-define your method simply as:

```
public int function1(inputObject input, boolean lead){
    if(lead) {
         LeadMaster lead= input.getLeadMaster();  
         PropertyUtils.setProperty(lead, input.getKey(), input.getValue());    
    } else {
         DealMaster deal= input.getDealMaster();
         PropertyUtils.setProperty(deal, input.getKey(), input.getValue());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Eugene. But I have many such master objects in my application. So I was thinking of a more generalized solution. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

First change `inputObject`.
Write  methods 
input.getMaster(Object object) 
input.setMaster(Object object) which sets and gets generic objects.
The you will be able to set `LeadMaster` and `DealMaster` both to that generically.

The Write an abstract class or use a super class which extended to both  classes which has `function1` and `function2`.
inside that abstract or super class use generic method you defined in `inputObject`

```
public int function(inputObject input){
    PropertyUtils.setProperty(input.getMaster, input.getKey(), input.getValue());
    return 0;
}
```